# Merge two arrays having different length based on value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays with each array containing time values.I need to merge two arrays and also need to be sorted.I also dont need duplicates.I have done like this.But its not working properly.I think the issues is related to keys.

```
$array1= Array ( [0] => 08:00 [1] => 08:10 [2] => 08:20 [3] => 08:30
 [4] => 08:40 [5] => 08:50 [6] => 09:00 [7] => 09:10 [8] => 09:20 
 [9] => 09:30 [10] => 09:40 [11] => 09:50 [12] => 10:00  ) 


$array2 = Array ( [0] => 08:00 [1] => 08:55 [2] => 09:50 [3] => 10:45
[4] => 11:40 [5] => 12:35  ) 

 $mergedtime_array = array_unique(array_merge(($array1),$array2));
```

the result is coming like this:

```
[0]=>8:00  [1]=>8:10  [2]=>8:20 [3]=>8:30 [4]=>8:40 
[5]=>8:50 (at[6]=> 8:55 should come for my logic,
but here its [6]=>9:00) [7]=>9:10 and so on.....
```

please help me

Comment: Check it it would be coming in the end according to me , i have tested it

Comment: @Hudixt ya..exactly..Its coming at the end.But I need it it to be in sorted order. But I have solved issue by putting sort() on the result variable, $mergedtime_array

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
$mergedtime_array = array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2));
```

Comment: @Techy, no you don't. You wrote some `(array1)` and I wrote `$array1` instead

Comment: For me its mixing the values

Comment: @Techy No, it's merging and deleting duplicates. That's what it should do and just does it.

Comment: I have solved my issue using sort() on the result, $mergedtime_array

Answer (score 0):

Put `sort()` on the result variable like this.

```
$mergedtime_array = array_unique(array_merge(($array1),$array2));

mergedtime_array =sort(mergedtime_array);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is working

```
$array1 = array ('0'=>'08:00','1'=>'08:10','2'=>'08:20','3'=>'08:30','4'=>'08:40', '5'=>'08:50', '6'=>'09:00', '7'=>'09:10', '8'=>'09:20','9'=>'09:30', '10'=>'09:40', '11'=>'09:50', '12'=>'10:00');

$array2 = array('0'=>'08:00','1'=>'08:55','2'=>'09:50','3'=>'10:45','4'=>'11:40','5'=>'12:35'); 

$resultArray = array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2));
```